# How can I get text to appear OVER the background image

Tags: html, css, navigation, background-image

I have successfully set a photograph as the background to my website and got it to fill the page so it is fixed and not tiled. Now I want the navigation bar to appear in the center of the image. However, the navigation bar is still hidden behind the background image despite the fact that I have set the image quality as "background". How can I make it appear in the center of the image.
Here is the coding I am using for the image:

```
<div>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img id="backgroundimage" src="websitebackground.jpg" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<style>
body, html { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; }
#backgroundimage { position:fixed; left:0; top:0; z-index:1; height:100%; width:100%; }
</style>
```

Comment: Make it an *actual* background image: `background: url(websitebackground.jpg)`

Comment: And don't use `<table>` for layout.

Comment: There's no text content in that code.

Comment: `Tables` for layout :( Use the correct `markup`.

Comment: Don't use divs for layout. Don't use any markup *for layout*. Use the appropriate markup to express the semantics and structure of your data. Then use CSS for layout.

Comment: It's all semantics.. :)

Answer (score 5):

dont use tables unless you are displaying tabular data. Instead do something like this

HTML

```
<div id="backgroundimage">
    //header content goes in here
</div>
```

CSS

```
#backgroundimage{
    background-image: url("path-to-image");
    //other styles here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't sourced the image correctly, you haven't sourced it as a background image use

```
<body background="websitebackground.jpg" id="backgroundimage">
```

That should put the image in the background behind the text.